# Generate test-jar of unit testing project and use in other maven projects

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, spring-boot

I created a unit-test maven project as a base project which other project can extend and use [Described here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html). Here is the pom.xml -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This generates two jars in target -

- unit-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- unit-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar

Now, I have some spring boot microservice projects say **service-a** and **service-b** which are using another maven project say **super-service** as dependency. **service-a** and **service-b** are using **super-service** as following declaration in respective services pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.super.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>super-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I have written unit test for classes in **super-service** by using above unit-test maven project which is working fine. The pom.xml of **super-service** is -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unit-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>unit-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But **service-a** and **service-b** is not working in same manner. I thought above dependency should get resolved through the base i.e. **super-service** but it's not and test gets fail. Then I have tried to repeat the same dependency declaration in each services pom.xml but still maven test gets fail.

I tried the other way described in that URL which tells to move source files from src/test/java to src/main/java but that also worked only for **super-service** project and not for **service-a** and **service-b**.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the wrong thing. You should not run the unit-tests of your dependencies -- if you don't think it can pass its tests you shouldn't be using it.

Only use a dependency when you have evidence that it passed its tests. This is controlled by your CI process which should only put successfully tested binaries in your binary repository. For most people this means that Jenkins should run your tests and if they all pass only then should it put the binary in nexus for you to depend on it. As it does the release to nexus the CI process, through maven, should also update the version number from a snapshot to a release version so that you're never depending on snapshots.

Comment: Thanks. Why steps are working for super-service and not working for service-a or b?